# Avoid duplicating fieldPath's when updating or creating documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Are there any way's to avoid duplicating strings everywhere when using TypeScript in Cloud Functions in Firebase?

I've tried making them enums, and that goes a long way.

```
enum Collections {
    SUBSCRIPTIONS = 'subscriptions-dev',
    ACTIVITIES = 'activity-dev'
}

enum ActivityKey {
    SUBSCRIPTION = 'sub',
    GROUP_ACTIVITY_ID = 'groupActivityId',
    GROUP_ACTIVITY_BOOKING_ID = 'groupActivityBookingId',
    ACTIVITY_NAME = 'activityName',
    ACTIVITY_START = 'activityStart',
    BOOKABLE_EARLIEST = 'bookableEarliest',
    BOOKABLE_LATEST = 'bookableLatest',
    STATE = 'state'
};
```

Then I can for example do:

```
const activityRef = admin.firestore().collection(Collections.ACTIVITIES);
return await Promise.all(subscriptions.map(async (subscriptionDocument) => {
    const sub = await subscriptionDocument.get();
    const groupActivityProductId = sub.get(SubscriptionKey.GROUP_ACTIVITY_PRODUCT_ID);
    const refreshToken = sub.get(SubscriptionKey.REFRESH_TOKEN);
...
```

**Now here's the problem**, when I want to create or update keypaths, using `set()` or `update()` functions, it expects a dictionary - and I can't use the enums as keys in dictionaries.

```
await activityRef.doc().set({
  sub: sub.ref,
  groupActivityId: activity.id,
  activityStart: new Date(activity.duration.start),
  bookableEarliest: new Date(activity.bookableEarliest),
  bookableLatest: new Date(activity.bookableLatest),
  instructor: activity.instructors.empty ? "-" : activity.instructors[0].name,
  lastChecked: new Date(),
  activityName: activity.name,
  state: ActivityState.NEW
})
```

If I write `ActivityKey.SUBSCRIPTION` as key, I get `',' expected ts(1005)`

Comment: But isn't `state: ActivityState.NEW` also an enum? Is that field accepted by firestore?

Comment: @ralemos It's OK to have the enum in the "value" part of the dictionary, it's the "key" part that is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found the answer myself!

If I wrap the key in `[]`, like this:

```
await activityRef.doc().set({
    [ActivityKey.SUBSCRIPTION]: sub.ref,
    [ActivityKey.GROUP_ACTIVITY_ID]: activity.id,
    [ActivityKey.ACTIVITY_START]: new Date(activity.duration.start),
    [ActivityKey.BOOKABLE_EARLIEST]: new Date(activity.bookableEarliest),
    [ActivityKey.BOOKABLE_LATEST]: new Date(activity.bookableLatest),
    [ActivityKey.INSTRUCTOR]: activity.instructors.empty ? "-" : activity.instructors[0].name,
    [ActivityKey.LAST_CHECKED]: new Date(),
    [ActivityKey.ACTIVITY_NAME]: activity.name,
    [ActivityKey.STATE]: ActivityState.NEW,
    [ActivityKey.HAS_SENT_CANCEL_REMINDER]: false
})
```

It works!

Comment: I'm trying to use enums for callable functions and getting the data out with the enum keys but it's not working. does this approach also work for this case?  --> exports.FIR_write_createOffer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { 

    const offerDate = data[FIR.k_offerDate];

Comment: I'm using node js btw